# Why am I getting an Exception in Application start method in JavaFX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am currently learning how to make GUI's. I copied and pasted this code into the Intellij IDEA. I have had other GUI programs work, but this specific one so far has given me this error.

I've tried looking at other posts regarding this issue, and a lot of them seem to deal with FXML elements. I am just confused.

```
package sample; 

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class ShowImage extends Application {
    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Create a pane to hold the image views
    Pane pane = new HBox(10);
    pane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    Image image = new Image("image/us.gif");
    pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image));

    ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image);
    imageView2.setFitHeight(100);
    imageView2.setFitWidth(100);
    pane.getChildren().add(imageView2);

    ImageView imageView3 = new ImageView(image);
    imageView3.setRotate(90);
    pane.getChildren().add(imageView3);

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setTitle("ShowImage"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
}

/**
 * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
 * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

I keep getting this error.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1107)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:617)
at IDK/sample.ShowImage.start(ShowImage.java:18)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1099)
... 11 more
Exception running application sample.ShowImage
```

Comment: Try a valid URL such as `https://i.imgur.com/kxXhIH1.jpg` to see the difference

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Look for the last *Caused by* in the stack trace you posted, i.e.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
```

Then look for your class `ShowImage` in the stack trace, i.e.

```
at IDK/sample.ShowImage.start(ShowImage.java:18)
```

I'm guessing the offending line is:

```
Image image = new Image("image/us.gif");
```

In other words, "image/us.gif" is not the correct URL for the image.

Are you familiar with the method `getResource()` in class `java.lang.Class`? It returns a URL which you can then use to create your `Image`.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize that it was not valid.

Comment: @OnionTal It's "valid" but it's probably pointing to the wrong location (i.e. _or resource not found_). If you use a string with no scheme to create an `Image` it interprets the path to be relative to the root of the classpath.